# How can I transform commonjs to es2015 module with babel plugin?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs, rollupjs

I use the webpack2 to build my web and I want to benefit from tree-shaking, which only works with es2015 modules.

So I want to ask for commonjs to es2015 transformer of babel plugin like this rollup plugin https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs.

Comment: FYI, OP is asking for a plugin or transform here - not actually asking for an entire library so I don't see this as being off topic. Would be the same as asking "how can I transform..." and getting a babel plugin as an answer.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0):

One such plug-in is babel-plugin-transform-commonjs-es2015-modules.
It can be installed by running:

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-commonjs-es2015-modules
```

Then add `'plugins':['transform-commonjs-es2015-modules']` to your babel configuration.